# Change in character's location with key frame messes up cloth simulation

Tags: rigging

I'm using cloth simulation and my problem is when I change the character location with key frame to a far location the cloth will mess up is there a way to pause the cloth and resume it to not make this happen
I can't seem to find a solution

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution changing the cloth simulation mass to 0 before Changing location than after 2 frames change it back to original cloth mass